# How to design a login page with different role

Tags: c#, user-interface

Tools: vistual studio 2010

language : c#

requirement:
I want to design a login page with different role.

for example Role1, Role2, Role3, and each role go to different website.

Now i have two option but feels not perfect.

Option 1 : use three buttons to click button go to different page to login.

Option 2 : only use one login form ,userName(), password(). we just validate the role according the input username and password in c# code. got the role property and go the corresponding page.

which one is better?

or someone has better idea?

Comment: **Option 2** is the best option, you don't want users to **"decide"** which role they should be in. You also don't want it to be be "publicly known" that you have **Role 1, 2 and 3** available in the back-end of your application. You should add a code sample of what you have tried thus far, otherwise you might get down voted, or your question might even end up being closed.

Comment: How about I downvote your question for not reading this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Comment: First, there's a [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com) area that might be better suited to this question.  Option 1 sounds "clunky", especially if there's a chance of more roles in the future.  If by Option 2 you mean the role will be determined by who they are (the user is shown no options) then this may be OK, providing users don't (often) have to switch roles.  If they do, you could have a drop-down on the login screen (providing, as jacqijvv says, you don't mind "advertising" the roles).  If you do, users would have to be logged into their "preferred" role with an option to change

Comment: @TripeHound beat me to the http://ux.stackexchange.com/ link, where you might have to describe your question a bit more. I think for example, if your "Role1", "Role2" and "Role3" were something like "Investors", "Users" or something, having separated roles on before the login doesn't seem like a bad thing. Whereas if it were "Admin" or "User" where Admin is like User + more capabilities, then the mapping might be okay to centralize on the login page. This is something the people over at ux might be able to answer better with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the user log in first, and then you can show the associated roles for this user to choose from.

You can show a new page for roles, or use a single form for login and roles with Ajax.
This is up to you.